Spark submit is throwing error when uploading parquet to nutanix object store
I am getting below exception when uploading parquet files to nutanix object store through pyspark code.

Exception:


/data/spark3/spark3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py:238: FutureWarning: Python 3.6 support is deprecated in Spark 3.2.
  FutureWarning
24/09/14 17:01:32 INFO internal.SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
24/09/14 17:01:32 INFO internal.SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/data/*/*/spark-warehouse'.
24/09/14 17:01:32 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b7a539a{/SQL,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
24/09/14 17:01:32 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2e735b9c{/SQL/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
24/09/14 17:01:32 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@38b3da2d{/SQL/execution,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
24/09/14 17:01:32 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@76a8649d{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
24/09/14 17:01:32 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6c0cf9c4{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
24/09/14 17:01:40 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (10.1.89.55 executor 4): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:500)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:321)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: regular upload failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.extractException(S3AUtils.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.putObject(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.close(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopPositionOutputStream.close(HadoopPositionOutputStream.java:64)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.end(ParquetFileWriter.java:1106)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:132)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:164)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseCurrentWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1496)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:311)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3DataSource$Utils.cleanupDataSource(S3DataSource.java:48)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1867)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.putObjectDirect(S3AFileSystem.java:1603)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.lambda$putObject$5(WriteOperationHelper.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:322)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.retry(WriteOperationHelper.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.putObject(WriteOperationHelper.java:428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.lambda$putObject$0(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:438)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor$RunnableWithPermitRelease.run(SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor$RunnableWithPermitRelease.run(SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.java:196)
        ... 3 more


Specifications


Spark version - 3.2.1
Python version - 3.6
JDK version - 1.8.0_422
Scala version - 2.12.15


Code:

from jproperties import Properties
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
CONST_DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
def main():
print(" ****** starting process ****** ")
property_path = sys.argv[1]
config = Properties()
with open(property_path, 'rb') as config_file:
    config.load(config_file)

access_key = config.get("object.store.access.key").data
secret_key = config.get("object.store.secret.key").data
end_point = config.get("object.store.endpoint").data

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("PARQUET_TEST") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", access_key) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", end_point) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum", "100") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multiobjectdelete.enable", "false") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider") \
    .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

log_level = config.get('log.level').data
sc.setLogLevel(log_level)

file_path = config.get("file_path").data + '/temp'

data = [("Alice", 29), ("Bob", 31), ("Catherine", 25)]
transactions_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

transactions_df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(file_path)

print("completed processing")

main()

Command used to run
spark-submit --jars jars/hadoop-aws-3.2.3.jar,jars/hadoop-common-3.2.3.jar,jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.373.jar,jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.373.jar,jars/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.373.jar project/parquet_test.py project/application.properties



you are mixing AWS SDK jars. all you need is the big fat aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.373.jar, which not only has a consistent set of aws classes, it includes shaded versions of all its dependencies, so you don't hit other problems related to versions of jackson, httpclient, netty and more
fix: remove the other aws- jars from the classpath
